# extract urls for js & css files from html? (using node.js)

Tags: html, node.js, html5-appcache

I want an array of urls from an html string, although only from the following tags:

- link href="http://example.com/foo.css"
- script src="http://example.com/foo.js"

I would like these urls so I can put them into an appcache manifest file.  I use an appcache manifest builder, but it only analyzes static files that I am serving locally.  It is working great, but it doesn't automatically include the external static js/css files that I am including in my html.

I would like to be able to parse the html string using node.js.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). It is an implementation of core jQuery for node.

For example:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    request = require('request');

request('http://www.stackoverflow.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var linkHrefs = $('link').map(function(i) {
      return $(this).attr('href');
    }).get();
    var scriptSrcs = $('script').map(function(i) {
      return $(this).attr('src');
    }).get();


    console.log("links:");
    console.log(linkHrefs);
    console.log("scripts:");
    console.log(scriptSrcs);
  }
});
```

Outputs:

```
Victors-MacBook-Pro:a kohl$ node test.js 
links:
[ '//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=6cd6089ee7f6',
  '//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69',
  '/opensearch.xml',
  '//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=317033db9646',
  '/feeds' ]
scripts:
[ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js',
  '//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=e3a448574e16' ]
```

Comment: This is cool.  I want an npm package that pulls urls like this.  I'm not sure if I  want it to pull from a single file, or from a directory, or perhaps from jade files.  I do know that I want something like this, so that I can append it to result of npm pkg appcachegen which only rolls though local files (and doesn't read them for urls as you have shown above).  A combination of both would make a fine appcache manifest.